# How to force a View to rerender in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following code

```
struct TriggerButton: View {
    @State private var confettiCounter: Int = 0
    @Binding var mode: ConfettiMode
    @Binding var showText: Bool
    @State private var counter = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                confettiCounter += 1
                if showText {
                    withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: 0.5)) {
                        showText = false
                    }
                }
                counter += 1
                if counter == 3 {
                    counter = 0
                    mode = mode.next()
                }
            } label: {
                Text(mode.icon)
                    .font(.system(size: 100))
                    .shadow(radius: 15, x: 5, y: 5)
            }
            .confettiCannon(counter: $confettiCounter, num: 70, confettis: mode.items, colors: [.red, .green, .yellow, .pink, .purple, .orange], confettiSize: 10, rainHeight: 300, openingAngle: Angle.degrees(30), closingAngle: Angle.degrees(150), radius: 500)
        }
    }
}
```

when the mode changes, I expect the view to be rendered. But instead, mode.icon gets updated but mode.items inside the confettiCannon does not. Why is that and how to fix?

Confetti is a library from https://github.com/simibac/ConfettiSwiftUI

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: I'd guess that `confettiCannon` takes a value of `mode.items`, not as a binding. If you're not sure, please show us the `confettiCannon` implementation.

Comment: @lazarevzubov I cannot it's a library located here https://github.com/simibac/ConfettiSwiftUI

Comment: What is ConfettiMode?

Comment: @loremipsum it's just an enum to keep track of what confetti to show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a look at the library and believe it's because of [this](https://github.com/simibac/ConfettiSwiftUI/blob/2a5797c5ada9aaca77338e7df1b1913cea909994/Sources/ConfettiSwiftUI.swift#L100) mistake in `ConfettiCannon`:

```
// first converts your confettis to shapes.

_confettiConfig = StateObject(wrappedValue: ConfettiConfig(
 num: num,
 shapes: shapes,
```

A `StateObject` is a "source of truth" thus cannot depend on any input that might change, which in your case it does. `wrappedValue` is an auto-closure that is only called once thus it only receives the first version of your confetti shapes (and all your other params) and is unaware of your changes.

In their [demo](https://github.com/simibac/ConfettiSwiftUIDemo/tree/main/ConfettiSwiftUIDemo) project they show the confetti via a `sheet`, which will clear the `@StateObject` on dismiss and create a new one on the next presentation, so you could do the same. Otherwise submit an [issue](https://github.com/simibac/ConfettiSwiftUI/issues) requesting to allow modifications to `ConfettiConfig` while it is presented.

If this is just a fun project, as a quick hack, after `.confettiCannon` you could use `.id(confettiCounter)` which will force it to update but in a very inefficient way.